# Como criar um relacionamento NxN na classe IdentityRole com uma classe criada por mim?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

Tenho um mapeamento automático dos `Controllers` e suas `Actions` que executo na inicialização da aplicação (arquivo `Global.asax`).

Utilizo isso para dar permissão ao usuário à determinado `Controller x Action` se ele possuir aquela combinação de direitos de acesso. `Controller + Action + Role`.

Preciso então criar o relacionamento `MenuItem x Roles`. Porém não sei como adicionar isso na aplicação. Será um relacionamento `N x N`.

Então tenho o seguinte:

```cs
public class MenuItem
{
    public MenuItem {  
        Roles = new HashSet<IdentityRole>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(40)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]        
    [ForeignKey("Menu")]
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
    public virtual Menu Menu { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("MenuItems")]
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Dai então tentei:

```cs
namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
{
    public partial class IdentityRole
    {
        public IdentityRole {
            MenuItems = new HashSet<MenuItem>();
        }

        [InverseProperty("Roles")]
        public virtual ICollection<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Porém, o Visual Studio reclama erro em algumas partes do código dizendo que a classe IdentityRole existe tanto em `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramewrk` quando em `App.Domain` (onde ficam as classes de minha aplicação).

---

#### Tentei também

Excluir a `partial class` de `IdentityRole` e deixei a classe `MenuItem` com a propriedade de navegação declarada assim:

```cs
public class MenuItem
{
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Porém, fazendo dessa forma o EF cria um campo `MenuItem_Id` dentro da tabela de `Roles` (`AspNetRoles`), entendendo como um relacionamento `1 x N`.

**Como fazer para criar esse relacionamento?**

Comment: Não lembro se é possível fazer uma `partial` de `IdentityRole`. Eu faria outra classe derivada de `IdentityRole`.

Comment: Tô achando muito complicado isso de reaproveitar o que está escrito. Escreva outras classes e use elas. Até acho que dá pra fazer com a Fluent API mas a aplicação vai fazer muita coisa em automático, e isso torna a vida do programador um inferno.

Comment: Falei porcaria. Depois eu te dou uma resposta ;)

Comment: Isso aí. Desculpe a bola fora. Já tô meio cansado hoje.

Answer (score 2):

Com a indicação do Cigano ficou fácil de resolver.

Criei uma outra classe herdade de `IdentityRole`, nela adicionei o relacionamento que preciso e passei a utilizar essa classe em vez da `IdentityRole`.

Assim:

```
public class Role : IdentityRole
{
    public Role() {
        MenuItems = new HashSet<MenuItem>();
    }

    [InverseProperty("Roles")]
    public virtual ICollection<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
}
```

E passei a utilizá-la:

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public MenuItem() {
        Roles = new HashSet<MenuItem>();
    }

    [InverseProperty("MenuItems")]
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

E então uma tabela para o relacionamento `NxN` foi criado e o módulo está funcionando.

Comment: Exatamente isso. +1.